# PGP encryption in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: encryption, informatica-powercenter, pgp

We have a requirement to extract a flatfile from one application into the Informatica server & load it thereon. However, we need to apply PGP encryption on the file before extraction & decrypt it once it's in the Informatica server.

Can anyone please tell me what is the process, and what are the requirements, functionality needed to achieve this ?

We are using Powercenter HotFix 4 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica will expect a clear delimeted or fixed length flat file which you won't be providing if it is pgp encrypted so I don't see it will be possible to even define the source in such circumstances.

What you should be looking toward is doing the pgp decryption upstream (e.g. smart loadbalancer like an F5 device)... really you should be taking this up with Networking experts

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sftp and generate public and private key, Informatica supports Sftp but you may have to generate the RSA keys before using the Sftp.

Thanks
MKrishnan